# Getting a document using REST API for Azure CosmosDB

Tags: php, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying CosmosDB Emulator using REST API from PHP.  For that I'm using [AzureDocumentDB-PHP](https://github.com/cocteau666/AzureDocumentDB-PHP).

This wrapper library is referring to the MSDN documentation for the REST API.  I'm seeing a difference between MSDN documentation and learn.microsoft.com

For example, to retrieve a single document [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn803957.aspx) says use the following syntax:

```
https://{databaseaccount}.documents.azure.com/dbs/{_rid-db}/colls/{_rid-col}/docs/{_rid-doc}
```

Whereas the [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/get-a-document) says use the below syntax:

```
https://{databaseaccount}.documents.azure.com/dbs/{db-id}/colls/{coll-id}/docs/{doc-id}
```

Note the difference, MSDN uses `_rid` (system generated id), where as learn.microsoft.com uses just the `id` (user generated id).

The mentioned PHP library which is using MSDN syntax works fine with the _rid (system generated id).  If I try to use the user generated id, I get the following error (for trying to get a db):

```
{"code":"Unauthorized",
 "message":"The input authorization token can't serve the request. 
            Please check that the expected payload is built as per the 
            protocol, and check the key being used. Server used the
            following payload to sign: 
            'get\ndbs\ndbs/db_test\nthu, 25 jan 2018 10:28:30 gmt\n\n'\r\n
              ActivityId: a43be1a0-c35b-4438-bb83-522204d3f589, 
             Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.19.102.5"}' (length=388)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually,The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn803957.aspx) doc and [doc.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/get-a-document) are both cosmosdb REST APIs.

However , the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn803957.aspx) doc is stopped updating in `July 14, 2015`.Obviously, the Azure Cosmos DB REST API is constantly being updated and optimized, as shown in the [x-ms-version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/common-documentdb-rest-request-headers) parameter which is required in the request header.

The [AzureDocumentDB-PHP](https://github.com/cocteau666/AzureDocumentDB-PHP/blob/ffe2eab6d6b8b02e70682e17ca8c61a43e04b9ab/phpdocumentdb.php) uses the old version of Azure Cosmos DB REST API which supports `_rid` of resources , so you can not use it with `id` of resources. The `x-ms-version` parameters are different.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an author of AzureDocumentDB-PHP.

This is because of creating an authorize token problem.
Resource Link should be like "dbs/db_test" when with id of resource.

See next link and Example Encoding. https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/rest/api/documentdb/access-control-on-documentdb-resources?redirectedfrom=MSDN#constructkeytoken

I will fix this issue in future.